# Why is `i` being taken as 1 always in for-loop

Tags: for-loop, lua, string-formatting, increment

I wrote this simple script to update a table in MySQL. For that, I created a for-loop and tried the following ([codepad link](http://codepad.org/sXKJan4O)):

```
sUpdate = [[UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '%s'
WHERE `date` = '%s'
AND `fid` > 50000]]

for i = 1, 12 do
  print( i )
  sOldDate = "2009-"..tostring(i).."-10"
  sNewDate = "2010-09-"..tostring(i)
  sUpdate = string.format( sUpdate, sNewDate, sOldDate )
  print( sUpdate )
end
```

The output follows:

```
1
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
2
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
3
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
4
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
5
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
6
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
7
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
8
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
9
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
10
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
11
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
12
UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '2010-09-1'
WHERE `date` = '2009-1-10'
AND `fid` > 50000
```

As you can see the `print(i)` is printing just fine, but both the `sOldDate` and `sNewDate` have i being treated as **1**. Then I changed the `sOldDate` and `sNewDate` as follows:

```
sOldDate = string.format("2009-%d-10", i)
sNewDate = string.format("2010-09-%d", i)
```

And I am still getting the output of both dates as: *2009-1-10* and *2010-09-1* as seen [here](http://codepad.org/c8KkzORY).

What could be problem with this loop. I have worked on such loops for a long time and they've never ever let me down until today.

I think it's just some silly mistake of mine which I am not able to identify. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: im no lua expert but i=1 as set in the for loop and never seems to be incremented i.e. i++

Comment: @NicholasKing `Lua`s for-loops are programmed that way. Check [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)

Comment: i was just doing some reading and around Lua loops and can see my comment is incorrect, like i say no Lua expert and was more of an observation than an answer. Thanks for the correction though. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is that you are overwriting `sUpdate` every time.

The first time, you will overwrite the string placeholders `%s`, and after that, the string will not change again.

Try renaming the inner `sUpdate`. And I think you want all the variables as `local`?

```
local sUpdate = [[UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '%s'
WHERE `date` = '%s'
AND `fid` > 50000]]

for i = 1, 12 do
  print( i )
  local sOldDate = "2009-"..tostring(i).."-10"
  local sNewDate = "2010-09-"..tostring(i)
  local sUpdate = string.format( sUpdate, sNewDate, sOldDate )
  print( sUpdate )
end
```

**Edit:** As you can see above, I have kept your variable names, but the inner `sUpdate` doesn't shadow the outer one, because it's declared `local`. All variables in Lua are global by default, so it's good advice to make sure you use declare local variables with `local`. I would opt to have different variable names, something like:

```
local sUpdateTemplate = [[UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '%s'
WHERE `date` = '%s'
AND `fid` > 50000]]

for i = 1, 12 do
  print( i )
  local sOldDate = "2009-"..tostring(i).."-10"
  local sNewDate = "2010-09-"..tostring(i)
  local sUpdate = string.format( sUpdateTemplate, sNewDate, sOldDate )
  print( sUpdate )
end
```

Comment: Hmm, as I said, some silly mistake of mine. I normally declared sUpdate inside the loop, and hence never faced any trouble. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: Also, I hope you don't mind me choosing **furq** 's answer over yours as he's new to SO, and in need of some score. ^_^

Comment: I think you should choose the answer you think is best, for posterity.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you need to rename sUpdate inside the loop to avoid overwriting the outer one and breaking string.format().  You can then use %02d in string.format() to zero-pad numbers to at least two digits in length:

```
local sUpdate = [[UPDATE `latest`
SET `date` = '%s'
WHERE `date` = '%s'
AND `fid` > 50000]]

for i = 1, 12 do
  print( i )
  local sOldDate = string.format("2010-%02d-10", i)
  local sNewDate = string.format("2010-09-%02d", i)
  local update = string.format( sUpdate, sNewDate, sOldDate )
  print( update )
end
```